# MySQL: Group by Austral year?

Tags: mysql

Let's say we have a simple table like so

```
DATE          VALUE
--------------------
2013-01-01    23
2013-06-12    34
2013-07-22    788
2013-12-16    234
2014-01-23    56
2014-04-19    88
2014-09-23    7987
2014-11-05    66
2015-02-17    987
2015-05-05    896
```

Now let's suppose we want to extract the mean values grouped by year, we would use

```
SELECT AVG(`VALUE`) FROM tablename GROUP BY YEAR(`DATE`)
```

However, what if we define the year not from January to December, but rather from July to June (which makes quite a bit of sense for a lot of data if you're living in the Southern hemisphere).

I am sure there must be an easy way to achieve a July YEAR to June YEAR+1 grouping. It just seems to elude me.

**-- EDIT --**

Awesome! Two good solutions arrived within minutes of posting this question, that both deserved to be accepted. I accepted Roland's solution because of its brevity, but Leo Tara's reply made me aware that I forgot about outputting the associated austral year. So based on both answers I came up with this solution which does exactly what I was asking for:

```
SELECT 
YEAR(`DATE` - INTERVAL 6 MONTH) as `australyear`,
AVG(`VALUE`) 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY YEAR(`DATE` - INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add 6 month to the date when grouping. I don't know the exact syntax in case of mysql, sorry.

Pseudocode:

```
SELECT AVG(`VALUE`) FROM tablename GROUP BY YEAR(`DATE` + '6 MONTHS');
```

Comment: The syntax would be `YEAR(DATE + INTERVAL 6 MONTH)`

Comment: I knew there was an elegant solution!

Comment: On second thought, substracting the interval allows the corresponding austral year to be determined correctly (see my edit). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT AVG(`VALUE`)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY 
    CASE
        WHEN MONTH('DATE') BETWEEN 1 AND 6 THEN YEAR('DATE') - 1
        ELSE YEAR(`DATE`)
    END
```

If you want to show year on field list you must rewrite your query in this way:

```
SELECT
     CASE
        WHEN MONTH('DATE') BETWEEN 1 AND 6 THEN YEAR('DATE') - 1
        ELSE YEAR(`DATE`)
    END, AVG(`VALUE`)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY 
    CASE
        WHEN MONTH('DATE') BETWEEN 1 AND 6 THEN YEAR('DATE') - 1
        ELSE YEAR(`DATE`)
    END
```

[Test on Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b487/7/0)

Comment: I was actually working on an edit of my post based on a combination of Roland's and your replies. Roland's is concise but yours made me realise that it would be quite helpful to add the actual Austral year to the query result. Roland's solution would provide two rows with year 2013. I wish I could accept both of your answers. But definitely a vote up from me. Cheers!

Comment: @Tomm: Ok, have a nice day ;)